# Scilab colorbar - fist and last color smaller

Tags: colors, range, colorbar, scilab

I try to plot with Scilab a plot containing also a colorbar.
I already changed the position of colorbar ticks that they are equally spaced.
But the colors are not! The last and first color is always smallar no matter which plot i use!
How can I Change the range of the colors within the colorbar?

Thanks!

[Colorbar whith desired color changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd0rE.jpg)

```
// data
x = linspace(0,1,81);
z = cos(2*%pi*x)'*sin(2*%pi*x);
zm = min(z); zM = max(z);
clf()
//simple cmap
r = [1,0,127.0/255,1,1,1,1];
b = [1,1,1,1,127.0/255,0,0];
g = [1,1,0,0,0,0,1];
cmap = [r',b',g'];
gcf().color_map = cmap;
colorbar(zm,zM)
Sgrayplot(x,x,z)

ticks = gcf().children(1).y_ticks
ticks(2)=linspace(-1,1,8)'
for i=1:size(ticks(2),1)
    ticks(3)(i) = string(ticks(2)(i))
end
gcf().children(1).y_ticks = ticks
```

Comment: Somehow I can't open that picture. Can you edit your question and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I have added a example above...I create some random data and plot it including a colorbar. I change the ticks of the colorbar according to the number of colors in the colorbar. So i want the ticks to be exactely at the line where the color changes. Unfortunately thats not the case...

Comment: Your code don't run in Scilab 5.5.1. : `gcf().color_map = cmap;` returns an error

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in Scilab 6.1.0.

Please see the Sgrayplot example #3 on the colorbar() documentation page @ https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/colorbar.html
[image]